# TypeError: prettyFormat.format is not a function @testing-library/react@13 with jest@26

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have been trying to upgrade my codebase to work with testing-library/react but it gets challenging day by day. I am trying to run a unit test that just checks for a text to be in the document but I am stuck at the following error:

```
    TypeError: prettyFormat.format is not a function

  53 |       </Provider>
  54 |     );
> 55 |     expect(screen.getByTestId('attribute-component')).toBeInTheDocument();
     |                   ^
  56 |   });
  57 |
  58 |   it('should match snapshot', () => {

  at prettyDOM (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/pretty-dom.js:111:37)
  at Object.getElementError (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/config.js:36:52)
  at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:76:38
  at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:52:17
  at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:95:19
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/test/javascript/spec/app/modules/components/account-attributes/attributes2.spec.tsx:55:19)
```

This is my software info:

- Node: 14.15.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/bin/node
- npm: 6.14.8 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/bin/npm
- jest: ^26.6.3 => 26.6.3
- @testing-library/react@13

This is the test that I am writting:

```
describe('attributes changes', () => {
const mpProps = {};
const historyMock = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: ['/'], keyLength: 0 });

beforeEach(() => {
  historyMock.push('/account-attribute');
});

it('should render attribute component', () => {
 render(
   <Provider store={reduxMockStore}>
     <Router history={historyMock}>
       <Attributes {...mpProps} />
     </Router>
   </Provider>
 );
 expect(screen.getByTestId('attribute-component')).toBeInTheDocument();
});

it('should match snapshot', () => {
 const { container } = render(
  <Provider store={reduxMockStore}>
    <Router history={historyMock}>
      <Attributes {...mpProps} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
 expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
});
});
```

screen.debug() also prints the same error as above. however, screen.getByText is working good.

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. These are my findings.

Turns out I had multiple version of pretty-format in my codebase due to which the app was not able to resolve to proper pretty-format lib.

To find all the packages using pretty-format you can run

```
npm ls pretty-format
```

This will print all the packages using pretty-format with their version number. You can also check package-lock.json if you are feeling adventorous.

Then I used console

`require.resolve('pretty-format')`

to figure out the path of which version of pretty-format was being loaded by the @testing-library/dom as mentioned in the stacktrace above.

When it console logged the output, I found the culprit as "junit". I had junit on an old version due to which I was getting this error. Once I upgraded junit from v10 to v15, this issue was resolved and require.resolve() printed the proper location of pretty-format and I am not getting this issue anymore.